# Handling changing variables with a Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking to get an idea of how best to handle the following.

I have a Jenkinsfile on my master branch that runs something like

```
node {
  stage 'Build stage 1'
    git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '${JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_ID}', url: 'git@github.com:application_1'

  stage 'Build stage 2'
    git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '${JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_ID}', url: 'git@github.com:application_2'

  stage 'Build stage 3'
    git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '${JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_ID}', url: 'git@github.com:application_3'


}
```

So it builds 3 separate applications which all connect to each other in the process.

What i am looking to do is have a way that when a feature branch is created that build will need to run on different branches for each application. Whilst this can be changed manually and committed, when any merge into master is completed that information will still be present and then change the master build.

Is there an efficient way to handle this kind of setup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs somewhat, you want to define a build script that can be used to build the master branch, or any other feature branch.

The basic idea, then, is to make the branch be a parameter to the build.  You can define parameters to the Jenkins build job, and those are rendered as Groovy variables in the pipeline script.

You can default the variable to "master".

You spawn the build from whatever is watching for commit events in your repository, and you have it execute the "buildWithParameters" Jenkins URL, passing the branch name.

That's the basic idea.

Comment: Hi, I understand the build with parameters but not all the branches will be of the same name, they could be all different. Any ideas? Thanks